# Create a ybar interval from given bar widths

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable, bar-chart

I am collecting data using the [NASA Task Load Index](http://humansystems.arc.nasa.gov/groups/TLX/), which gives 6 scales and has a weight associated with each scale. I am trying to plot the mean value for each scale using a ybar interval graph, whereby the width of each bar is set by the weight for the corresponding scale, similar to the picture below taken from the manual.

[image: Desired output]

I have managed to create an additional column that should give me the right interval data (see table), but the bar width doesn't look correct, nor am I able to then use the symbolic x coords as labels for the bars.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread{
  Scale    Mean  Weight
  MD      53.25    3.50
  PD      12.22    1.50
  TD      18.46    1.75
  FR      45.75    3.00
  OP      59.18    2.45
  EF      22.15    2.80
  Overall 38.175   2.50
}{\tlxweightedratings}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
  columns/Scale/.style={string type},
  create on use/Interval/.style={
    create col/expr={\pgfmathaccuma + \thisrow{Weight}}},
  columns={Scale, Mean, Weight, Interval},
]{\tlxweightedratings}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[ybar interval, xtick=data,
      nodes near coords,
      %symbolic x coords={MD, PD, TD, FR, OP, EF, Overall},
  ]
    \addplot+ table[x=Interval, y=Mean,
      create on use/Interval/.style={
        create col/expr={\pgfmathaccuma + \thisrow{Weight}}},
    ] {\tlxweightedratings};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ybar interval` plot style uses the `x` value of the current data point as the left edge of the column, and the `x` value of the next data point as the right edge of the column. With your method of calculating the `Interval`, the first column starts at `3.5` and stretches to `5`, so it has a width of `1.5`. You want it to start at `0` and stretch to `3.5`, however, so you should change your code to use `\prevrow` instead of `\thisrow`. You also need to add a dummy data row to your table, so the width of the last column can be calculated as well.

You don't actually want `symbolic x coordinates`, since they're always equally spaced. Simply use `xticklabels={MD, ...` to set the labels.

`nodes near coordinates` don't currently work satisfactorily with `ybar interval`, since they're always positioned above the start of the columns, not their centers.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread{
  Scale    Mean  Weight
  MD      53.25    3.50
  PD      12.22    1.50
  TD      18.46    1.75
  FR      45.75    3.00
  OP      59.18    2.45
  EF      22.15    2.80
  Overall 38.175   2.50
  Dummy    0       0
}{\tlxweightedratings}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
  columns/Scale/.style={string type},
  create on use/Interval/.style={
    create col/expr={\pgfmathaccuma + \thisrow{Weight}}},
  columns={Scale, Mean, Weight, Interval},
]{\tlxweightedratings}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    ymin=0,
    ybar interval, xtick=data,
      xticklabels={MD, PD, TD, FR, OP, EF, Overall},
  ]
    \addplot+ table[x=Interval, y=Mean,
      create on use/Interval/.style={
        create col/expr={\pgfmathaccuma + \prevrow{Weight}}},
    ] {\tlxweightedratings};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Spot on as usual, thanks a million. I don't actually need the overall column in this chart, so it serves as a nice dummy column. Encouraging to see that I wasn't completely off either :-)